# Is it safe to compare boolean variable with 1 and 0 in C, C++?

Tags: c++, c

Consider the code

```
bool f() { return 42; }

if (f() == 1)
    printf("hello");
```

Does C (C99+ with stdbool.h) and C++ standards guarantee that "hello" will printed? Does

```
bool a = x;
```

is always equivalent to

```
bool a = x ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: I'm sure this question is a duplicate, but *A prvalue of type bool can be converted to a prvalue of type int, with false becoming zero and true becoming one*.

Comment: Why you do such comparison?

Comment: Exactly what Xiaoge Su said: Why do you even care? Such code is never as expressive as explicitly writing `false` or `true`.

Comment: @XiaogeSu: I code for MCU and often my booleans are logic levels, e.g. `if (gpio_read(jumper) == 1) gpio_write(led, 1);`. It is more readable than simply `if (gpio_read(jumper))` or with `== true`.

Comment: I would have thought you would have printed "The meaning of life." instead of "hello" :)

Comment: the only boolean that I can see is the one generated by the implicit cast according to the return type of your function `f`, this is a really cumbersome way of expressing yourself. Try to write this in a much simpler manner.

Comment: @Corvus I believe in C/C++, `0` in `if` is always `false`, while non-`0` in `if`, including `1`, `-1`, etc. is always `true`.

Comment: @XiaogeSu: it's obviously right. My doubts was about implicit conversion 42 to 1.

Comment: @Corvus if you `return 42;` while your function type is `bool()`, then this is the same to `return true;'

Comment: This question may be a duplicate and it may not be.  The earlier question was poorly posed, so it is hard to tell.  This question is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, `bool` is a built-in type. Conversions from any type to `bool` always yield `false` (0) or `true` (1).

Prior to the 1999 ISO C standard, C did not have a built-in Boolean type. It was (and still is) common for programmers to define their own Boolean types, for example:

```
typedef int BOOL;
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1
```

or

```
typedef enum { false, true } bool;
```

Any such type is at least 1 byte in size, and can store values other than `0` or `1`, so equality comparisons to `0` or `1` are potentially unsafe.

C99 added a built-in type `_Bool`, with conversion semantics similar to those for `bool` in C++; it can also be referred to as `bool` if you have `#include <stdbool.h>`.

In either C or C++, code whose behavior is undefined can potentially store a value other than 0 or 1 in a `bool` object.  For example, this:

```
bool b;
*(char*)&b = 2;
```

will (probably) store the value `2` in `b`, but a C++ compiler may *assume* that its value is either `0` or `1`; a comparison like `b == 0` or `b == true` may either succeed or fail.

My advice:

- Don't write code that stores strange values in `bool` objects.
- Don't compare `bool` values for equality or inequality to `0`, `1`, `false`, or `true`.

In your example:

```
bool f() { return 42; }
```

Assuming this is either C++ or C with `<stdbool.h>`, this function will return `true` or, equivalently, `1`, since the conversion of `42` to `bool` yields `1`.

```
if (f() == 1)
    printf("hello");
```

Since you haven't constructed any strange `bool` values, this is well behaved and will print `"hello"`.

But there's no point in making the comparison explicitly. `f()` is already of type `bool`, so it's already usable as a condition. You can (and probably should) just write:

```
if (f())
    printf("hello");
```

Writing `f() == 1` is no more helpful than writing `(f() == 1) == 1)`.

In a real program, presumably you'll have given your function a meaningful name that makes it clear that its value represents a condition:

```
if (greeting_required())
    printf("hello");
```

Comment: @Corvus: I strongly disagree that `== 1` makes the condition more readable. I find `if (greeting_required())` much more readable than `if (greeting_required() == 1)` -- and the former is correct even if the function returns `int`. No, the standard doesn't protect against `*(char*)b = 2`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You are missing a step though. "0" is false and every other int is true, but f() always returns true ("1"). It doesn't return 42, the casting occurs in "return 42;".

Comment: Thanks. My doubts are from old times when I write in C without boolean type, just using the hack `typedef unsigned char bool`. In this case "hello" from my code will not printed.

Answer (score 3):

In C macro bool (we are speaking about the macro defined in `stdbool.h`) expands to `_Bool` that has only two values 0 and 1.

In C++ the value of f() in expression `f() == 1` is implicitly converted to int 1 according to the integral promotion.

So in my opinion this code

```
bool f() { return 42; }

if (f() == 1)
    printf("hello");
```

is safe.

Comment: C has `bool`?? Since when? I'm behind on the times I guess.. AFAIK, `BOOL` is anything > 0 and `FALSE` is 0? Similar to WinAPI's `BOOL` which is defined as `INT` and can be anything that isn't 0.. yes? I don't know I guess.. I usually see `typedef enum boolean{false, true};`

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames We are speaking about the macro bool defined in stdbool.h

Comment: Ohh.. well +1 from me anyway. Didn't know it had that.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames: C has built-in boolean type since 1999.

Comment: @Corvus In fact it s not a boolean type. It is an integral type with the domain of two values.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Привет, Влад. What is the difference between "boolean" and "integer with two values"?

Comment: @Corvus It is a good question. I did not check but it seems that in C you should explicitly convert function pointer to _Bool for example in an assignment statement _Bool b = f;. In C++ such a conversion can be implicit. In such languages as C# and Java bool is not an integral type.

Comment: http://ideone.com/izn7u7  bool can only hold 1 and 0 I think. Int can hold a variety of ranges. Some languages have bool strongly typed. Pascal is one where bool cannot be implicitly converted to int.

Answer (score 0):

The only real trick that I know of, that is useful with pre-C99 environments is the double negation

```
int a = 42;
if ( (!!a) != 0 ) printf("Hello\n");
```

this will print `Hello` because the result of the `!!` operation is a boolean that is `true` when the value is non-zero, `false` otherwise. But this is gonna cost you 2 negation to get the boolean that you want, in modern standards this is redundant because you will get the same result without the `!!` and it's a result granted by the language.